# Генерация случайных чисел в Stream (Java 8)

Tags: случайные-числа, java-stream, java-8

Поток ввода-вывода случайных чисел можно создать вот так:

```
Stream<Double> randoms = Stream.generate(Math::random);
```

`Math::random` выдаст, как я понимаю, случайное число между(равное) `0.0` и `1.0`.
 Как можно задать диапазон, к примеру, между 20 и 50?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не стоит использовать для этого генератор. В Java 8 у объекта класса `Random` имеются методы для создания потоков:

- `doubles()` - генерирует бесконечный поток значений в диапазоне [0, 1)
- `doubles(long size)` - создаёт поток с указанным количеством значений в диапазоне [0, 1)
- `doubles(double origin, double bound)` - создаёт бесконечный поток значений в указанном диапазоне [origin, bound)
- `doubles(long size, double origin, double bound)` - создаёт поток с указанным количеством значений в указанном диапазоне

Также есть методы `ints` и `longs` для создания потоков соответствущих типов.

Answer (score 5):

```
Stream<Double> randoms = Stream.generate(()->Math.random()*30+20)
```